# Trying to get push notifications using Parse.com not working on device

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

So i am trying out Parse.com Push notification service.

I have done all the steps etc and when i try to run on the simulator the app runs but when i try to run it on my Iphone Device (Iphone 5s) the application crashes with the following error code:

```
015-01-08 17:28:45.607 PickMeUp[451:60b] -[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]:         
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1576016f0
2015-01-08 17:28:45.610 PickMeUp[451:60b] *** Terminating app 
due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1576016f0'
```

This is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[Parse setApplicationId:@""];

// Register for Push Notitications
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes

                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings]; // The app crashes here
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];



return YES;
```

}

**EDIT**

My iphone is not fully updated. Version is 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    // Register for Push Notitications
    if ([application respondsToSelector: @selector (registerUserNotificationSettings :)]) {
          UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                   categories: nil ];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
       } else {
           //ios7
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
            UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
            UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
            UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

       }
```

Comment: Implicit decleration of function 'selector' is invalid in C99 @TonyMkenu and: Use of undeclared identifier 'registerUserNotificationSettings'; did you mean 'UIUserNotificationSettings'?

Comment: sorry, update the code, mistyped `selector` - must be `@selector`

Comment: Wow it worked, thank you!. Could you explain why it worked?
Also if i wanted to make it work for ios 6 where could i check what to write then? @TonyMkenu

Comment: You can use this code in any iOS vers without any modif. Tks

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, yet it got me going in right direction and after days of searching I found this other stack link:
[RegisterUserNotificationSettings is not working in ios 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294281/registerusernotificationsettings-is-not-working-in-ios-6-1) .
Added it in and everything is good.

Comment: This should be a comment.