# App Failing in iOS7.1 - due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, unrecognized-selector

I searched for an answer and found lots but nothing worked for me in fixing my error and the majority of the answers told me to delete items with the yellow exclamation mark, yet I can't find any.

My builds run fine in all iOS simulators running iOS8 - but as soon as I try with iOS7.1, it fails regardless of phone/ipad choice.

Here is the error log:

---

```
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.839 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.866 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 Store item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.873 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 StoreCategory item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.873 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 Photo item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.874 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 Review item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.874 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 Rating item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.875 OpenPatios[26206:f03] Deleted 0 News item(s)
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.880 OpenPatios[26206:607] {{0, 0}, {320, 324}}
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.899 OpenPatios[26206:607] -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79714ca0
    2015-03-30 14:21:18.901 OpenPatios[26206:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79714ca0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x039501e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x034998e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x039ed243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x0394050b ___forwarding___ + 1019
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x039400ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   OpenPatios                          0x0012ea55 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 2053
        6   UIKit                               0x0257914f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
        7   UIKit                               0x02579aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
        8   UIKit                               0x0257e667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
        9   UIKit                               0x02592f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
        10  UIKit                               0x02593555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
        11  UIKit                               0x02580250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
        12  GraphicsServices                    0x05882f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
        13  GraphicsServices                    0x05882a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x038cbca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x038cb9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x038f668c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x038f59d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x038f57eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        19  UIKit                               0x0257dd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
        20  UIKit                               0x0257ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        21  OpenPatios                          0x00162e7d main + 141
        22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0425f6d9 start + 1
        23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

---

Any clear direction on how to fix this is GREATLY appreciated as I am learning more about coding again.

Comment: Can you show the code you have in your app delegate for registering devices for remote notifications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegisterUserNotificationSettings is not working in ios 6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294281/registerusernotificationsettings-is-not-working-in-ios-6-1)

Comment: Duplicate; this is covered elsewhere and has answers with working code for a app to work on either iOS 7 or less, or iOS 8.

Answer (score 3):

As per the Apple docs, registerUserNotificationSettings is only available in iOS 8 and greater.  You will have to implement this some other way if you want to support older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

From the official Apple documentation

Availability

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
This registerUserNotificationSettings method use can't use for ios7.

**Update 1**

Maybe you could use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

instead of registerUserNotificationSettings